# Rewrite code for htaccess for specific parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am non ech guy and trying to get a rewrite code which I can use in htaccess for file specific parameter. Basically there are some urls with "?m=0" OR "?m=1" which I want to redirect. Like

```
Old url: www.abc.com/nokia.html?m=1

New URL: www.abc.com/nokia.html

Old url: www.abc.com/nokia.html?m=0

New URL: www.abc.com/nokia.html
```

I want to redirect code which is applied only when these 2 specific `m=1` OR `m=0` are present. In case there is any thing else than `m=1` or `m=0`, the redirect shall not get applied.

I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ ]*)\?

RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

But it gets applied in all urls and hence I can access admin pages where "**?**" is used with other parameter.

Can anyone plz mention the code which I can use in very specific cases. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thnx.. but there are many ursls and Nokia.html is just one exapmple, I have around 300+ urls which ends with differently like samsung.html, tablet.html, so plz edit the code accordingly..

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thnx a ton it worked perfect. There is one more add on to this needed. in home pages there is no html in end of the url and hence this code doesnt work. like www.abc.co.in/?m=0 OR www.abc.co.in/?m=1 Can u plz give the code for just these 2 urls. I have to use this also for same domain. best rgds

Comment: Hi Anubhava, EXCELLENT, its works perfectly fine, thnx a ton....God bless u buddy, have grt time... best rgds, Jai